# Authenticating to Firebase in a Powershell Script

Tags: json, powershell, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

What I have: I've built a script that pulls information about my printers, converts that information to a JSON object, with the goal of pushing that object to Firebase using its Rest API.

What I know: Firebase appears to be using whats called JWT (JSON Web Tokens).

The script that I have is dated. I never took the time to set up authentication previously, and want to implement it now. However, now auth isn't as simple as getting your Secret from the Firebase Console.

I'm sure a direct answer isn't likely (here is how you auth to firebase using powershell). There seems to be some JWT modules for powershell, and I'm wondering if I might be able to use those to attempt to authenticate to Firebase. Maybe there are better options I'm just not seeing.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!